# Ubuntu 12.04.1 and 12.10 USB mouse and touchpad lag

Tags: mouse, touchpad, hp

I have tried Ubuntu 12.04.1 and Ubuntu 12.10, and I get a very nasty lag while using my USB mouse and/or touchpad. I have tried Fedora and it's a little better on the lag, but I still get it. I know it's not a hardware problem, because it works fine on Windows. I have googled this problem and can not find a fix for this issue. Please, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing Desktop environment, does it lag as much in xfce as it does in Unity?

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu, Slapt Man ! Could you please edit your question to tell what kind of hardware you are talking about (brand and model) ?

Answer (score 1):

In 10.04.4, it helped to modify the touchpad's properties by `synclient SingleTapTimeout=0` and `synclient FastTaps=1` in the Terminal.

You can see all settings with `synclient -l`.

Furthermore, I was annoyed that long-distance-drag&drop was not working with more than 2 clicks by default, so I had to set `LockedDrags=1` and `LockedDragTimeout=360`.

Still, my touchpad does not work flawlessly like in Windows, for example double clicking and sliding the finger on the touchpad after the 2nd click before releasing to mark text or scroll bars only works like in 1 out of 5 tries...

Similar [problem with long-distance-drag&drop](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1453295) without solution, so any further help would be appreciated.